# Create Node.js app that gets data from api and creates table in html file with that data

Tags: node.js, json, npm, axios

We are working with this API: 
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users 
And I need to create a node.js app, that will 
get users list from api and create an html file content from 0 with a table inside it about that users.

I have written down this task with html/css/js with fetch and it works and now I do not know how to do it with node.js.
For now, I only have this code:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
axios.get(url)
.then(function (response) {
    //console.log(response.data);
    let arr = [];
    arr = response.data;
    fillTheTable(arr);
  })
.catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Comment: Can I get some recomendations on how to do it?

Comment: Since you already have a javascript file why not just use ajax?

Comment: I am sorry, but I was told to not use express. Thank you for the response though <3

Comment: The homework is around axios and node.js. that is why ((

Comment: You should be able to create a server and use routing with node native language. The rest is really similar. Im sure theres a lot of documentation about it :)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use a minimal MVC Express App:

At `app.js` you start the server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var index = require('../controllers/index');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.get('/', function (req, res) { // index url of your web app. Will call to index controller
  index
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

At `controlles/index.js` you specify the logic of your main url (get the data of your API and render it to a view to transform to HTML):

```
const axios = require('axios');

const asyncUtil = fn =>
    function asyncUtilWrap (req, res, next, ...args) {
        const fnReturn = fn(req, res, next, ...args)
        return Promise.resolve(fnReturn).catch(next)
    }

module.exports = {
  index: asyncUtil(async (req, res, next) => {
      let users = await axios(url)
      res.render('index', {users})
  })
}
```

You will specify the HTML in a pug view at `views/index.pug`, that will transform it to HTML:

```
table
  thead
    tr
      th Id
      th Name
      th Username

  tbody
    each user in users // iterate through users json
      tr
        td #{user.id}
        td #{user.name}
        td #{user.username}
```